# Twilio studio Gather Widget Not Detected voice input

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, ivr

I am using Twilio studio flow to make an IVR and not want to miss a single command from customer. When we say a sentence Gather Input widget is working but we say a single word like sales .Widget not detected any word and trigger no input .Can someone give suggestion how we used Gather input in our flow that it detect even a single word. I used hints and set language as well. I also used speech model like number and command but I am not sure how we used it .

Waiting for Answer.
Thanks

I am trying to detected single words as well from customers in Twilio studio

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do both well and need to direct your user to either say something short or say something long. I recommend you go with short for best results. Additionally, if you don't want to miss anything your customer said you might want to record your call and to post call analysis to see if there was anything important there. Honestly, if this is your first time introducing speech to your customers do this:

"Thank you for calling X, how may I help you?" 
Customer says whatever.

"Let's try this a different way for X press 1, for Y press 2."

This helps you to better understand what your customer's would normally ask for in their own words and then have a better idea if you really need to capture long sentences or short words.

david